# Valor None si el valor es vacio

Tags: django

estoy usando Django y tengo una funcion donde recibo distintos parametros, me gustaria que por defecto poner **None** (nulo) si no viene ningun parametro, recibo de la siguiente manera:

```
def MiFuncion(request):
  if 'nombre' in request.POST:
     nombre = request.POST.get('nombre')
  else:
     nombre = None
```

De esta manera si no recibo ningun valor defino None lo cual funciona bien, pero he visto que tambien usan algo asi:

```
nombre = request.POST.get('nombre', None)
```

Mi duda: Esta correcto esa forma de determinar None(nulo) si no recibe un valor ?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: En el metodo ```get``` de un diccionario si no se encuetra la llave, por defecto, se retorna ```None```, osea que este codigo ```request.POST.get('nombre', None)``` es lo mismo que escribir ```request.POST.get('nombre')```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta forma esta bien:

`nombre = request.POST.get('nombre', None)`

Lo que hace esta linea es que intenta obtener del diccionario el valor de la llave 'nombre' y en caso de que no exista asigna el valor por defecto None a la variable nombre. El valor por defecto se puede cambiar, mira [aquí](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/dictionary_get.htm).